# What is the sudden sharp pitch increase in Old Country/Rockabilly

Tags: terminology

You don't hear it much in country music nowadays but what is that technique or term where artists like Johnny Horton and the like make a sudden whoop or yelp at the end of a line ([North to Alaska](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JSt0NEESrUA) is a good example at 0:37-38).

I looked to see if it was twang, but that doesn't seem right. I even researched into the origins of most country and rockabilly-esque music, to see if it was a term originating in the African American Culture but no luck so far. Might it be yodeling?

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely NOT yodeling and "twang" can describe other aspects of the rockabilly country style of singing besides the sharp pitch increase you refer to.

I am not sure if there is actually an official name for that technique.

I call it a **"Hillbilly Hiccup"** and I have used it myself in some of my original country songs.  In fact I first herd the term "hillbilly hiccup" from the engineer in a recording studio where I was recording one of my songs.

That's not an official term, but it is descriptive and catchy - so I will continue to use that phrase to describe the technique until someone gives me a better term.

Comment: Oh I see! Also thanks for the edit I'm on Mobile. I was discussing different songs of that genre with a friend and it bugged me that I couldn't find any sort of info for it. I really like that technique and its difficult to find any good info on it. I guess I'll use this term unless someone comes along with anything official aha . Thanks for all the info 